# queueTrigger function not firing

Tags: c#, azure-functions, message-queue, queuetrigger

I have an Azure ServerLess C# project that I deployed out to azure with 2 functions both that should be trigger by their corresponding queues. I noticed only the first function firing but not the second one. All my settings are correct but I noticed if I reordered the functions around the top most function is the only functions that will be triggered. Is there some file I have to edit that I have edit to say there are 2 trigger functions.

Here is the main .CS file

```
[StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
public class QueueFunction
{
    ICollaborationClient _collaborationClient;
    ILogger<QueueFunction> _logger;
    public QueueFunction(ICollaborationClient collaborationClient, ILogger<QueueFunction> logger)
    {
        _collaborationClient = collaborationClient;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [FunctionName("ParticipantQueueFunction")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%ParticipantQueueName%")] ParticipantNotificationModel participantNotificationModel, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(participantNotificationModel, Formatting.Indented));

        await _collaborationClient.PostAsync("/api/ParticipantHub", participantNotificationModel, participantNotificationModel.Headers);

        log.LogInformation($"function processed participant id: {participantNotificationModel.ParticipantServiceModel.ParticipantId}");
    }
    
    [FunctionName("MessageQueueFunction")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%MessageQueueName%")] MessageNotificationModel messageNotificationModel
                            , ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageNotificationModel, Formatting.Indented));

        await _collaborationClient.PostAsync("/api/notifications/SendNotifications", messageNotificationModel.MessageServiceModel, messageNotificationModel.Headers);

        log.LogInformation($"function processed message id: {messageNotificationModel.MessageServiceModel.MessageId}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem both methods were named the same. I just reread my question.